# Getting $\sum_m a_{n,m}^2 (b_n^{k+1}-b_m^{k+1}) $ from $\sum_m a_{n,m}$ and $\sum_m a_{n,m} b_m^{k+1}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have two sequences $\{a_{n,m}\}$ and $\{b_{n}\}$.

Knowing only the two terms $\sum_m a_{n,m}$ and $\sum_m a_{n,m} b_m^{k+1}$, can I determine the value of the term
$$ \sum_m a_{n,m}^2 (b_n^{k+1}-b_m^{k+1}) $$

I tried taking the difference

$$ \left(\sum_m a_{n,m}\right) \left(\sum_m a_{n,m} b_n^{k+1}\right) - \left(\sum_m a_{n,m}  \right) \left(\sum_m a_{n,m} b_m^{k+1} \right) $$
but ended having extra terms!

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Shaun Thanks for the remark. I tried to modify the title, hope it is more informative now.